# How to make the Polygon tool the active tool when the Sketch widget opens?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, widget

Using the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API v4.18, I am adding the [Sketch widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Sketch.html). My goal is to have the Polygon tool as the only available tool, and to have this tool active when the widget opens.

I've been able to switch off all other tools using the `visibleElements` option:

```
visibleElements: {
  createTools: {
    point: false,
    circle: false,
    polygon: true,
    polyline: false,
    rectangle: false
  },
  selectionTools:{
    "lasso-selection": false,
    "rectangle-selection": false,
    "pointer-selection": false /* this has no effect - I don't know the correct name for this tool */
  },
  undoRedoMenu: false
}
```

However, the standard pointer *select* tool is shown by default, and is the active tool...

[image]

... and I need to click on the Polygon tool to activate it. How can I:

(a) not show the pointer select tool
(b) have the polygon drawing tool active by default?

The option `activeTool: 'polygon'` does select the polygon tool by default, but not correctly - the select tool is simultaneously selected, so neither tool works as expected:

[image]

See the demo at https://codepen.io/slead/pen/ZEBNpbd, based on the Esri [Sketch Widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=sketch-geometries) demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you are looking for, you need to start the action using the `create` method of the widget ([ArcGIS API - Sketch Widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Sketch.html#create)).

This is a possible way of doing it,

```
let handle = null;
handle = sketch.watch("state", state => {
    console.log(state);
    if (state === "ready") {
    sketch.create("polygon");
    handle.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, many thanks. I updated the demo at https://codepen.io/slead/pen/ZEBNpbd to include this

Comment: Glad it helps you!!